# Develop apps for the iPad 3's retina display without lion?

Tags: xcode, ipad

Is Xcode 4.3.1 (and therefore lion) required to develop apps for the iPad 3's retina display?

Or is there a way to develop for the new device using Xcode 4.2?  I'm not running lion yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking about iOS the iOS 5.1 sdk, then you will have to update to Lion and Xcode 4.3.1 to get it.

But as to the Retina display of the iPad 3, there is nothing special about it in the new sdk. So you can develop apps for the iPad 3 using Xcode 4.2. Just make sure you take into account the high resolution of the device when working with images and other graphics as you do with the iPhone Retina Display.

Comment: And how do you do that?  Is there another convention similar to @2x.png?

Answer (score 1):

This small hack may be able to help you: it presents how you could install the 5.1 SDK with an older version of Xcode that works on Snow Leopard.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/100229-snow-leopard-sdk-5-1-a.html

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you do need to develop using Lion and iOS 5.1. If you don't build with the latest SDK then the @2x graphics won't show up in the app.

Comment: is this a fact? I'm asking a question in another post and if so then I am going to have to upgrade a build machine.

Comment: It is a fact yes. I've experienced it myself, and now that I'm running Lion the @2x iPad artefacts are rendering correctly.